# How I can implement a chatbot using react chatbot kit?

Tags: reactjs, chatbot

I have implemented the chatbot using reactjs chatbot kit. I have used all the boiler plates from the documentation but the problem that I am facing is that when the user sends nothing by clicking the send button it shows in the UI. so how to avoid it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEqyH.png)

I am thinking about disabling the button when the box is empty.